# Extending a Theorem of Brualdi to Matrices with Infinitely Many Rows

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, convex-polytopes

This question is about extending a result on transportation polytopes from Brualdi regarding $m\times n$ matrices to the case when $m=\infty$.

**Notation**: Denote an $m\times n$ matrix by $A=[a_{i,j}]$, and consider sets  $K\subset\lbrace 1,2,\ldots, m\rbrace$ and $J\subset \lbrace 1,2,\ldots, n\rbrace$. Define $$A[K,J):=[a_{i,j}:i\in K, j\in\lbrace 1,2,\ldots,n\rbrace-J].$$

Denote by $N(R,S)$ by the class of all $m\times n$ nonnegative matrices with row sum given by the *positive* vector $R=(r_1,\ldots, r_m)$ and column sum given by the *positive* vector $S=(s_1,\ldots, s_n)\,\,\,$ ($N(R,S)$ is called a *transportation polytope*).

The following theorem is from Brualdi's *Combinatorial Matrix Classes*:[image]

I am trying to construct an $\infty\times n$ matrix with $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}r_m = \sum_{j=1}^ns_j=1.$ Will this theorem also hold when $m=\infty$? I tried extending the proof to the case $m=\infty$, but Brualdi's proof heavily relies on the fact that $m$ is finite.

**Update:** Here's what I have. Let $r_i', s_j'$ denote the row and column sums in the case $m=\infty$.  For a particular example, I can apply this theorem to prove the existence a $m\times n$ matrix for all sufficiently large $m$, where the column sums will necessarily be less than $s_j'$ (let's say $s_j' \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ tends to 1 as $m$ tends to $\infty$) and I am able to verify the inequality after we replace $m$ with infinity, but I am not sure if this implies the existence of the $\infty \times n$ matrix.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly (what is a pattern?), you are looking for a generalization of the [infinite Hall marriage theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489962/halls-marriage-theorem-for-infinite-system-of-finite-sets). Maybe you can generalize one of its proofs?

Comment: @ darij grinberg, it means that $A$ has $0$'s at entries $(i,j) $for which $W$ has a zero, and $A$ has a positive number at $(i,j)$ in locations for which $W$ has a $1$. @PeterTaylor I closed the other one.

Comment: but is $n$ finite?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes.

Comment: Oh, then it isn't a generalization of infinite Hall. The condition that the sum of the $r_i$ equals the sum of the $s_j$ shows that only finitely many $r_i$ are nonzero; then, the whole thing follows from the finite version.

Comment: @darijgrinberg How are only finite many of the $r_i$ nonzero? In my case, each $s_j$ is $1/n$ and the rows are indexed by integers $i$ which have no prime factor larger than the largest prime $\le n$ (so $m$ is unbounded but doesn't take on every integer). For such values if $m=i$, I have $$r_i=\frac{\prod_{p\le n, p\text{ prime}}\frac{p-1}{p}}{i}$$, so that $r_i$ is never zero and their sum is 1.

Comment: Oh, they're not integers!

Comment: Hm, if $n=m=2$, $r_1=r_2=s_1=s_2=1$ and $W$ consists of three 1's and one 0, what is the matrix with pattern equal to $W$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, in your example, one row will have all zeros, so that one of the $r_i$s is zero, and thus violates the assumption that all $r_i, s_j$ are positive.

Comment: I realize that I didn't originally state that the $R, S$ vectors were positive. I've edited it.

Comment: Why zeroes? $r_1=r_2=1$, and no other $r_i$'s.

Comment: @FedorPetrov  Sorry, I thought $W$ had 3 zeroes. First we'd have to check the inequalities in the theorem to ensure the existence of such a matrix. Since there is no matrix in this case, the inequalities must fail for some $L, K$.

Comment: My point is that in my example the inequalities hold, but the conclusion fails. We should probably replace the 'pattern $W$' to 'pattern contained in $W$'.